# Не импортируется класс из одного .py файла в другой

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

Мне необходимо переключение между окнами. Для этого я в один файл импортирую класс из другого файла.

Но если я импортирую класс, который изначально создаёт *Qt Designer* (я делаю шаблоны файлов в *Qt Designer*), то не работает часть кода, который я прописываю в "классе надстройке" если можно так выразиться.

А если я импортирую этот "класс надстройку", то выходит ошибка:

> class VocabularyTask4a(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, IdiomsTask_2):
> TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
> order (MRO) for bases QMainWindow, IdiomsTask_2

Как решить эту проблему?

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from IdiomsTask2 import IdiomsTask_2
import startcontents_rc


class Ui_StartPage(object):
    def setupUi(self, StartPage):
        StartPage.setObjectName("StartPage")
        StartPage.resize(677, 823)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(StartPage)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 681, 831))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/start/Images/contents/start page1.png"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 261, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color:white")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 420, 181, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: #1a75ff;\n"
"    border: 1px ;\n"
"    border-radius: 20\n"
" }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed  { \n"
"    background-color: #003380;\n"
" }\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        StartPage.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(StartPage)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(StartPage)

    def retranslateUi(self, StartPage):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        StartPage.setWindowTitle(_translate("StartPage", "Start Page"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("StartPage", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">Interactive Student\'s Book</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("StartPage", "Go to contents"))


class VocabularyTask4a(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, IdiomsTask_2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class StartWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_StartPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.firstwindow = VocabularyTask4a() #Первое окно - окно с вокабуляром (пометка для себя)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.gotofirstwindow)
        self.firstwindow.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.gotomainwindow)

    def gotofirstwindow(self):
        self.firstwindow.show()
        self.hide()

    def gotomainwindow(self):
        self.show()
        self.firstwindow.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    #StartPage = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    #ui = Ui_StartPage()
    #ui.setupUi(StartPage)
    #StartPage.show()
    w = StartWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**IdiomsTask2.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_IdiomTask_2(object):
    def setupUi(self, IdiomTask_2):
        IdiomTask_2.setObjectName("IdiomTask_2")
        IdiomTask_2.resize(1100, 642)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        IdiomTask_2.setFont(font)
        IdiomTask_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: #d580ff")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(IdiomTask_2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 1081, 58))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: #ffffb3")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #aa00ff")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 120, 421, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 125, 141, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 170, 421, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 180, 121, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 230, 421, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 230, 141, 21))
        self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 300, 141, 16))
        self.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 290, 421, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 360, 141, 21))
        self.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 360, 421, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 430, 141, 16))
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 400, 351, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 480, 141, 16))
        self.lineEdit_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 460, 301, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 80, 421, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 520, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: 1px ;\n"
"    border-radius: 15;\n"
"    background-color: #f2f2f2;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed  { \n"
"    background-color: #cccccc;\n"
" }\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 120, 491, 421))
        self.label_11.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label_11.setText("")
        self.label_11.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/page1/Images/Unit 4/4a/IdiomsImages/1_2.png"))
        self.label_11.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 570, 356, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: 1px solid black;\n"
"    border-radius: 10;\n"
"    background-color: #f2f2f2;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed  { \n"
"    background-color: #cccccc;\n"
" }\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 570, 355, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: 1px solid black;\n"
"    border-radius: 10;\n"
"    background-color: #f2f2f2;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed  { \n"
"    background-color: #cccccc;\n"
" }\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 570, 356, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: 1px solid black;\n"
"    border-radius: 10;\n"
"    background-color: #f2f2f2;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed  { \n"
"    background-color: #cccccc;\n"
" }\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.lineEdit.raise_()
        self.label_4.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_2.raise_()
        self.label_5.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_3.raise_()
        self.label_6.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_4.raise_()
        self.label_7.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_5.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_6.raise_()
        self.label_8.raise_()
        self.label_9.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_7.raise_()
        self.label_10.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.label_11.raise_()
        self.pushButton_7.raise_()
        self.pushButton_8.raise_()
        self.pushButton_9.raise_()
        IdiomTask_2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(IdiomTask_2)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1100, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        IdiomTask_2.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(IdiomTask_2)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        IdiomTask_2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(IdiomTask_2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(IdiomTask_2)

    def retranslateUi(self, IdiomTask_2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        IdiomTask_2.setWindowTitle(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Idioms Task"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;\">Unit 4a</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;\">Come rain or shine!</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Yumi is feeling                                       , so she won\'t be going to work today."))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Mo is                                  - his wife is pregnant"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "He can\'t continue going around with his                                      ; he must be more realistic about his problems"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Studying English is                                      . I\'m progressing so quickly"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "In my opininon, the whole thing is just "))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Once you have the basic home comforts, it\'s importnat to"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "I was going to go shopping, but it suddenly started                                     so I stayed home"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Fill in missing idioms"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Check"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Go to previous page"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Go to unit contents"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Go to next page"))
import images_rc

#'Класс надстройка'
class IdiomsTask_2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_IdiomTask_2 ):   
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.checkanswer)
        

        self.a1 = None
        self.b1 = None
        self.c1 = None
        self.d1 = None
        self.e1 = None
        self.f1 = None
        self.g1 = None

    def saveanswer(self):
        self.a1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.b1 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.c1 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.d1 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        self.e1 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        self.f1 = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        self.g1 = self.lineEdit_7.text()

    def checkanswer(self):

        self.saveanswer()

        if self.a1 == "under the weather":
            self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: green; background-color: white}")
        elif self.a1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: red; background-color: white}")

        if self.b1 == "on cloud nine":
            self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: green; background-color: white}")
        elif self.b1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: red; background-color: white}")

        if self.c1 == "head in the clouds":
            self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: green; background-color: white}")
        elif self.c1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: red; background-color: white}")

        if self.d1 == "a breeze":
            self.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: green; background-color: white}")
        elif self.d1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: red; background-color: white}")

        if self.e1 == "a storm in the teacup":
            self.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: green; background-color: white}")
        elif self.e1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: red; background-color: white}")

        if self.f1 == "save up for a rainy day":
            self.lineEdit_6.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: green; background-color: white}")
        elif self.f1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit_6.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: red; background-color: white}")

        if self.g1 == "raining cats and dogs":
            self.lineEdit_7.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: green; background-color: white}")
        elif self.g1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit_7.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: red; background-color: white}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    IdiomTask_2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    #ui = Ui_IdiomTask_2()
    #ui.setupUi(IdiomTask_2)
    #IdiomTask_2.show()
    w = IdiomsTask_2()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужен класс `class VocabularyTask4a`. Все что вам надо это `self.firstwindow = IdiomsTask_2()`. Обратите внимание, что вам надо раскомментировать импорты файлов ресурсов.

main.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from IdiomsTask2 import IdiomsTask_2

#import startcontents_rc                                        # <--- подключите



class Ui_StartPage(object):
    def setupUi(self, StartPage):
        StartPage.setObjectName("StartPage")
        StartPage.resize(677, 823)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(StartPage)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 681, 831))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/start/Images/contents/start page1.png"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 261, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color:white")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 420, 181, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: #1a75ff;\n"
"    border: 1px ;\n"
"    border-radius: 20\n"
" }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed  { \n"
"    background-color: #003380;\n"
" }\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        StartPage.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(StartPage)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(StartPage)

    def retranslateUi(self, StartPage):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        StartPage.setWindowTitle(_translate("StartPage", "Start Page"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("StartPage", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">Interactive Student\'s Book</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("StartPage", "Go to contents"))


#class VocabularyTask4a(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, IdiomsTask_2):
#    def __init__(self, parent=None):
#        super().__init__(parent)
#        self.setupUi(self)

class StartWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_StartPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
#        self.firstwindow = VocabularyTask4a() #Первое окно - окно с вокабуляром (пометка для себя)

        self.firstwindow = IdiomsTask_2()      # +++

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.gotofirstwindow)
        self.firstwindow.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.gotomainwindow)

    def gotofirstwindow(self):
        self.firstwindow.show()
        self.hide()

    def gotomainwindow(self):
        self.show()
        self.firstwindow.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    #StartPage = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    #ui = Ui_StartPage()
    #ui.setupUi(StartPage)
    #StartPage.show()
    w = StartWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**IdiomsTask2.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_IdiomTask_2(object):
    def setupUi(self, IdiomTask_2):
        IdiomTask_2.setObjectName("IdiomTask_2")
        IdiomTask_2.resize(1100, 642)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        IdiomTask_2.setFont(font)
        IdiomTask_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: #d580ff")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(IdiomTask_2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 1081, 58))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: #ffffb3")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #aa00ff")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 120, 421, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 125, 141, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 170, 421, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 180, 121, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 230, 421, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 230, 141, 21))
        self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 300, 141, 16))
        self.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 290, 421, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 360, 141, 21))
        self.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 360, 421, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 430, 141, 16))
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 400, 351, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 480, 141, 16))
        self.lineEdit_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 460, 301, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 80, 421, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 520, 121, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: 1px ;\n"
"    border-radius: 15;\n"
"    background-color: #f2f2f2;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed  { \n"
"    background-color: #cccccc;\n"
" }\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 120, 491, 421))
        self.label_11.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label_11.setText("")
        self.label_11.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/page1/Images/Unit 4/4a/IdiomsImages/1_2.png"))
        self.label_11.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 570, 356, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: 1px solid black;\n"
"    border-radius: 10;\n"
"    background-color: #f2f2f2;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed  { \n"
"    background-color: #cccccc;\n"
" }\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 570, 355, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: 1px solid black;\n"
"    border-radius: 10;\n"
"    background-color: #f2f2f2;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed  { \n"
"    background-color: #cccccc;\n"
" }\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 570, 356, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: 1px solid black;\n"
"    border-radius: 10;\n"
"    background-color: #f2f2f2;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed  { \n"
"    background-color: #cccccc;\n"
" }\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.lineEdit.raise_()
        self.label_4.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_2.raise_()
        self.label_5.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_3.raise_()
        self.label_6.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_4.raise_()
        self.label_7.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_5.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_6.raise_()
        self.label_8.raise_()
        self.label_9.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_7.raise_()
        self.label_10.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.label_11.raise_()
        self.pushButton_7.raise_()
        self.pushButton_8.raise_()
        self.pushButton_9.raise_()
        IdiomTask_2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(IdiomTask_2)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1100, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        IdiomTask_2.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(IdiomTask_2)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        IdiomTask_2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(IdiomTask_2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(IdiomTask_2)

    def retranslateUi(self, IdiomTask_2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        IdiomTask_2.setWindowTitle(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Idioms Task"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;\">Unit 4a</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;\">Come rain or shine!</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Yumi is feeling                                       , so she won\'t be going to work today."))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Mo is                                  - his wife is pregnant"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "He can\'t continue going around with his                                      ; he must be more realistic about his problems"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Studying English is                                      . I\'m progressing so quickly"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "In my opininon, the whole thing is just "))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Once you have the basic home comforts, it\'s importnat to"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "I was going to go shopping, but it suddenly started                                     so I stayed home"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Fill in missing idioms"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Check"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Go to previous page"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Go to unit contents"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("IdiomTask_2", "Go to next page"))
        
#import images_rc                                          # <--- подключите

#'Класс надстройка'
class IdiomsTask_2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_IdiomTask_2 ):   
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.checkanswer)
        

        self.a1 = None
        self.b1 = None
        self.c1 = None
        self.d1 = None
        self.e1 = None
        self.f1 = None
        self.g1 = None

    def saveanswer(self):
        self.a1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.b1 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.c1 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.d1 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        self.e1 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        self.f1 = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        self.g1 = self.lineEdit_7.text()

    def checkanswer(self):

        self.saveanswer()

        if self.a1 == "under the weather":
            self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: green; background-color: white}")
        elif self.a1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: red; background-color: white}")

        if self.b1 == "on cloud nine":
            self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: green; background-color: white}")
        elif self.b1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: red; background-color: white}")

        if self.c1 == "head in the clouds":
            self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: green; background-color: white}")
        elif self.c1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: red; background-color: white}")

        if self.d1 == "a breeze":
            self.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: green; background-color: white}")
        elif self.d1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit_4.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: red; background-color: white}")

        if self.e1 == "a storm in the teacup":
            self.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: green; background-color: white}")
        elif self.e1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit_5.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: red; background-color: white}")

        if self.f1 == "save up for a rainy day":
            self.lineEdit_6.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: green; background-color: white}")
        elif self.f1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit_6.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: red; background-color: white}")

        if self.g1 == "raining cats and dogs":
            self.lineEdit_7.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: green; background-color: white}")
        elif self.g1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit_7.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color: red; background-color: white}")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#?    IdiomTask_2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    #ui = Ui_IdiomTask_2()
    #ui.setupUi(IdiomTask_2)
    #IdiomTask_2.show()
    w = IdiomsTask_2()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

**Перед строчкой**

```
from IdiomsTask2 import IdiomsTask_2
```

напишите Import самого файла (Import IdiomsTask2), а потом уже пишите эту строчку